# Schedule report every month on 28th append with month and year name by PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

```
if((Get-date).day -eq 28) {
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "azurepolicies" -File "subcriptions|"$month"|"year".csv" -Content $storage.Content -Force
}
```

Error:

```
| A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
| 'year.csv'.
```

Comment: Your quotes are off, shouldn't have new quotes around month and year., Just one before subscriptions and ine after csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the [Set-AzStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-AzStorageblobcontent?view=azps-8.3.0)

```
    # Hopefully this will lead in you the right direction.  
    $Today = Get-Date
    if ($Today.day -eq 28) { 
        Set-AzStorageBlobContent `
        -Container "azurepolicies" `
        -File ("subscriptions{0}{1}.csv" -f $Today.Month, $Today.Year) `
        -Content $storage.Content -Force 
    }
```